# How to create wireless data communication between a power inverter and its LAN wired remote control

Tags: networking

I am planning to buy a power inverter for my solar power system. The inverter is something like this:

[https://www.ebay.com/itm/234002873642?hash=item367ba87d2a:g:ErwAAOSwAsJgpL~l&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4M4JHgoTY7Qcl7KDCUh4syWRnZ08XUIoIuWhJbD54HO8m04oNWBPNqT7MPYBv1NkhAI1M1LJtl%2FWrIA95ChfZ1LeHKwDV4Uxa%2FQ5D%2F1y3ICLfhs5Bj2yAqfnt1gD4kGzGLlhTwM%2Fi3KmJTUhVWhxN4J1Hj0fCtGX0CKm%2FD72Y7yoY%2BrJ4wCGaURqDoRKRgQFuyStlHaVoW1y%2BA7f5w0vHnWylECw18TzXk48yTf%2BeSXUAcYK3qeTEWfyb%2FoUud1GuCI4cpx%2FvyZqafEzjONNAoBCJueg5SfxSAveyTwpMqkZ%7Ctkp%3ABFBMlNOChahg](https://www.ebay.com/itm/234002873642?hash=item367ba87d2a:g:ErwAAOSwAsJgpL%7El&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4M4JHgoTY7Qcl7KDCUh4syWRnZ08XUIoIuWhJbD54HO8m04oNWBPNqT7MPYBv1NkhAI1M1LJtl%2FWrIA95ChfZ1LeHKwDV4Uxa%2FQ5D%2F1y3ICLfhs5Bj2yAqfnt1gD4kGzGLlhTwM%2Fi3KmJTUhVWhxN4J1Hj0fCtGX0CKm%2FD72Y7yoY%2BrJ4wCGaURqDoRKRgQFuyStlHaVoW1y%2BA7f5w0vHnWylECw18TzXk48yTf%2BeSXUAcYK3qeTEWfyb%2FoUud1GuCI4cpx%2FvyZqafEzjONNAoBCJueg5SfxSAveyTwpMqkZ%7Ctkp%3ABFBMlNOChahg)

As you see it has a wired remote control, however the location from where I want to control the inverter is about 100 feet from where the inverter would be. My search for solutions is two fold:

1. How can I establish a wireless connection between the inverter and the remote control so I don't have to pull out 100 feet of LAN cable between the two? (some kind of two piece external device I can plug both the inverter and the remote, so they can talk to each other)
2. Does anybody know of a way to control (turn on and off) the inverter through the internet from a laptop from any remote location?

I do have unlimited high speed WiFi internet.

Thank you for your ideas and advice

Erik

Comment: There does not appear to be any reference to the communications protocol for the remote. Using standard ethernet cable (RJ-45 reference) is meaningless without protocol. It's just 8 wires, no information. I did not see a link to a manual in the auction listing. Without knowledge of the communications protocol, anything is a guess.

Comment: Check with the manufacturer - they have a chat tool on their site for questions like this. It almost certainly cannot be controlled through your laptop. You may also want to check with them about the maximum length of cable, as some protocols like serial don't like to go past 50 feet or so